# how can I get the users which liked the video from Youtube api

Tags: youtube-api

I found that there is a api for user:

```
To request a feed of another user's favorite videos, send a GET request to the following URL. Note that this request does not require authentication.

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/userId/favorites
```

is there a api for video?, for example:

```
 https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/vidoes/videoId/favorites
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't find anything in the Data API reference which would suggest that it is possible to read *who* liked a video, only *how many* people did: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference and https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_ratings